# While doing npm install getting an error as "No such file or directory open"

Tags: node.js, npm

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:{{File_Location}}\node_modules.staging\mocha-20835964\lib\browser\progress.js'

and Error message as npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...int-stylish":"~0.1.3"'

I am trying the command npm-install in visual studio above is the error which I am getting.Please help me for the same.

Comment: What is your npm version?

Comment: It’s not npm-install it’s npm install and in shorthand npm i

Comment: npm version is '6.4.1'.I was using npm install(it was a typo please ignore) along with package name but still I am getting an error as "npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...int-stylish":"~0.1.3"'"

Answer (score 16):

delete `package-lock.json` first.
navigate to the root folder of your project and `npm cache clean --force`, then try `npm install`

Comment: `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 1):

What happen for me to get this error was when I runned `npm i` and closed or stopped before it was finished. Then to try to "fix" it, I deleted the `node_modules` folder and runned `npm i` again and started getting this error.

And the reason why this happens and `npm cache clean --force` fixes the problem is that npm have a cache on the files that it have already downloaded, but when I remove `node_modules`, it can't find the files name that are cached and should be in the `node_modules` and gives this error/warning.

Answer (score -3):

To install any dependency using npm is

```
  npm install module_name
```

For eg

```
  npm install path or npm i path
```

But not

```
 npm-install path or npm-install
```