# Error occurred while starting the npm server in the react project

Tags: reactjs

At first everything was running quite well but since I reset my laptop (I restored my files by coping the project files from the hard drive to the same folder) and when I tried npm start for the same react project it shows me an error.

**npm ERR! code ENOENT**

**npm ERR! syscall open**

**npm ERR! path C:\projects\react projects\tutorials\project-1\package.json**

**npm ERR! errno -4058**

**npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\projects\react projects\tutorials\project-1\package.json'**

**npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.**

**npm ERR! enoent**

**npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:**

**npm ERR!     C:\Users\devam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-06-18T11_26_05_693Z-debug.log****

even my package.json file is inside the project itself but still I am facing this error
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Well if I run the npm server for a new project it starts without any errors

Comment: is it possible that the path has changed after resetting your laptop?

Comment: what do you mean by path??

Comment: Well as per my understanding you mean the path where I have copied my files right ?but I checked it it's the same path as before, as much as I know.

Comment: Yes, normally this occurs because the file path of the project has changed.  Have you tried running npm install to see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: Well @Michael I tried npm install still the problem is there. but using npm install command all the node modules were updated, not the src files as far as I know the issue is with the package.json file as per the error message. so is there any way by which I can repair the project files or say replace the old in-built project files with the new one??? may be this can resolve the problem. If no then any other solutions??

Comment: Do you have this code in a remote repo?  If so, you could always just clone the repo to another file and then open it from there.  I would also look at this answer if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187582/enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory/52187773

Comment: Well thanks for the help @Michael, I don't know how but my problem is solved now probably from one of the tips I have received. If I encounter anything like this again I would ask for sure thanks again