# How to solve npm error "npm ERR! code ENOENT"

Tags: reactjs, npm

[npm start failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oih2J.jpg)

when i run start
this error is happening....any solution please

react:17.0.2, react-scripts: 5.0.0

Comment: You are in wrong directory or your project does not include package.json

Comment: Thanks! @TDiblik

Comment: Does this answer your question? [enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187582/enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)