# How to solve npm error "npm ERR! code ENOENT" after trying ```npm run build```

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I am working on a symfony 5 project and i am using Webpack. When a try to run "npm run build", i get this error!

```
    $ npm run build

> build
> encore production --progress

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\ssh
npm ERR! path F:\web\nash-cm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\ssh ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-26T14_09_13_962Z-debug.log
```

I did research on it and i fund that i have to first clean the cache whit command `npm cache clean`, what i have done and delete afeter **node_modules folder and package-lock.json**, what a have also done and at the end, i have to run `npm install`, what give me the same error!
Can somebody help me?

Comment: did you check out the `xxx.-debug.log` ? can you try `npm run build --force` probaly `C:\ssh` is somehow faulty configurated somewhere, are you calling the npm from the symfony project-directoy?

Comment: Thank @john Smith  for your answer. Now it work's fine. The problem was that i added two environments variables(C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\ssh) on a inappropriate place,on **ComSpec** instead of **Path**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK now. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187582/enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory).

The problem was that npm was not able to find those two paths `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\ssh`. they where on a inappropriate environment variable,**on ComSpec instead of Path**.

To solve the problem, i deleted them from **ComSpec** environment variable.
what I remember is that `npm ERR! code ENOENT` is caused by npm's inability to find or read a file.
Hope my answer can help somebody else.